# Complexity of DB Operations in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Does anyone have a guide to computing the complexity of various operations in postgresql?
Such as selects, joins (in the from vs the where), group, aggregation, cartesian products, etc?

I am looking for something in Big O notation.

Comment: It's not Big O notation, but an explain plan in postgres will give you a pretty good idea of the complexity of various operations. Just prepend the query with EXPLAIN ANALYZE and you will see the cost, time taken, and other factors. Might not be what you are looking for, but I at least wanted to throw it out there.

Comment: Yeah, explain is good for specific queries, but I want something general that can be used as a guide for query design decision-making.

Answer (score 10):

What you are asking for doesn't and can't exist, because there isn't a 1:1 relationship between type of operation and complexity.  Consider a basic select operation, for example.  This could map into various kinds of plans and the planner makes decisions regarding estimated complexity of each plan. For example, suppose we:

```
CREATE TABLE my_index_test (id int primary key); -- creates an index too!
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM my_index_test where id = 0;

                                            QUERY PLAN                      

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------
Seq Scan on my_index_test  (cost=0.00..34.00 rows=2400 width=4) 
    (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
  Total runtime: 0.045 ms
 (2 rows)
```

Now the planner in this case decides (correctly) that using an index is needless complexity.  So consequently even a simple query has multiple possibilities and PostgreSQL tries to choose the least complex plan given what it knows.

The one exception is that commit and rollback both have O(1) complexity.

Comment: So there would be a complexity related to a sequential scan and another to an index scan? Would they be O(n)?

Comment: Where n is the number of rows in the table, I would expect the efficiency to be approx O(n) for a sequential scan and O(n^1/2) for an index scan.  Of course they have different coefficients, etc. and so a sequential scan is often cheaper on small tables.  BTW, this is before getting into nested loop vs merge vs hash joins.....  But the point is that your sql-level operations don't really correspond to anything definite on the lower level, and you certainly can't expect that they will all have similar complexity or efficiency profiles.

Comment: Then if the OP changed the question's context from sql commands to database engine tasks the answer would be _yes, there is or it is possible to build such a list_ ? By chance I just happen to have an interest in this subject (complexity) right now and from my [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) research it looks like the cost of a binary search is O(log n) in average and O(n) in the worst case. I guess the search in an index is a binary one. Isn't it?

Comment: It would be possible to build such a list of database engine tasks.  The difficulty of course is that this is not great in terms of making decisions since you can't micromanage the planner that much.  As far as indexes, it involves a binary search, but depending on the index type it may involve quite a bit more in addition.  That's another thing is that you have a fairly large number of kinds of indexes on PostgreSQL....

Comment: I think such a list would be useful for people looking to create efficient queries and rank database operations

Answer (score 5):

The answer depends on the quality of the index. 
Gerenarally with the binary block size.
If no index, search is `O(n)`. 
If index, search is `O(log n)`. 
You can also set which datastructure you want to use in which index. 
For instance, B-tree as the method of the partial index [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createindex.html) and about the complexities of different operations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) for the binary operations:

```
        Average     Worst case
Space   O(n)        O(n)
Search  O(log n)    O(log n)
Insert  O(log n)    O(log n)
Delete  O(log n)    O(log n)
```

Doing simple testing. 
The underlying block size affects the logarithmic speed, about which I have a thread [What is the block size of Partial Index with B-tree?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/111603/69807) because `log_b n` is the how the logarihmic things are done, which makes the operations faster than the default binary ones but possibly having some costs with the space (not sure how to present it there):

```
        Average     Worst case
Space   O(n)        O(n)         % not sure about this here
Search  O(log_b n)  O(log_b n)
Insert  O(log_b n)  O(log_b n)
Delete  O(log_b n)  O(log_b n)
```